# Cannot get support FragmentManager inside Fragment - ViewPager inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am trying to create activity with NavigationDrawer, and inside one Fragment, i want to place ViewPager. The problem is, when i am trying to create new SectionPagerAdapter (class extending FragmentPagerAdapter), i cant get proper FragmentManager for constructor.

There is code of onCreateView of navDrawer fragment where i want to place ViewPager:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_anime, container, false);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //There is problem:
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

SectionPagerAdapter class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Section 1".toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return "Section 2".toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return "Section 3".toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and DummySectionFragment:

```
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section+number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_anime, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) 

//My code here - http request and listView creating

        }

    }
```

Now i have an error when calling getChuldFragmentManager(), which says that android.app.FragmentManager cannot be applied to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

**SOLVED**
I was extending android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment in my class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this

> android.support.v4.FragmentManager cannot be applied to android.app.FragmentManager

you are using `android.app.FragmentManager` in `SectionsPagerAdapter` class. Change it to `android.support.v4.FragmentManager`.

Comment: Sorry, i have wrote it wrong, i meant that android.app.FragmentManager cannot be applied to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, and i cant change constructor because then i cant call super(fragmentManager)  correctly

Comment: If your fragment that contains this line `mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());` extends support fragment `getChildFragmentManager` returns a support fragment.

Comment: And that was my problem. I was extending android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment, You solved this problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your import `import android.app.FragmentManager;` and add this

`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: its solved by faranjit, anyway thanks a lot for help.